# Take ScreenShot of a current Screen using a background service in android

Tags: android

I need to write a service that will take screenshots of the current screen at specific intervals.After studying I found that there are two ways to do so :

1. By rooting the device and access system level privileges to read framebuffer and convert it into a bitmap

2.Use ASL library to take screenshots

Since I don't want to root the device,I decided to go with ASL but whenever I run the demo code,I get native service not found.Please suggest me the steps to implement ASL and make the code to work.

Comment: "whenever I run the demo code,I get native service not found" -- when you contacted the developers of ASL, what did they tell you?

Comment: I didnot contact ASL Developers.How can I get the support of ASL developers?Is there any community for ASL developers?

Comment: "How can I get the support of ASL developers?" -- hmmm... I would have thought they would have a Google Group or something on their project, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for ASL to work, you have to connect to a PC once after every boot, and start the native service via ADB.

I guess you missed that, thus the service is not found.

You can find more on that here: http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/UserGuide